# Which is the maximum allowance for an employer to respond to an annual leave request?

Tags: united-kingdom, legal, holidays

My employer consistently not responding to a holiday request. By law and contract, my notice period should be twice as big as the total requested days.
However, I cannot find any information about the maximum days that the employer has to respond to a request.

Reasoning says that there must be somewhere a clause that regulates this matter. Does anyone know what that clause is?

For those who asked. I am currently working in the UK and the retail sector.

Comment: Ok, what is your question?

Comment: We can't comment on law without knowing what country you're in...

Comment: As far as I know, in the US there is no such clause unless your contract or company policy creates one. Start by asking your employer.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info.

Working in the UK
Sector is Retail

Comment: I contacted the citizens advice. According to them they do not have enough relevant information on the subject in order to give me an advice. They suggested that if the matter is of critical importance to address my issue with a solicitor. A bit extreme solution for 10 days of holiday don't you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to https://www.gov.uk/holiday-entitlement-rights/booking-time-off-

> The general notice period for taking leave is at least twice as long as the amount of leave a worker wants to take (eg 2 days’ notice for 1 day’s leave), unless the contract says something different.
>
> An employer can refuse a leave request **but they must give as much notice as the amount of leave requested**, eg 2 weeks’ notice if the leave requested was 2 weeks.

I'm not seeing a maximum time from the time of the request, but they do have to respond in the amount of time requested, i.e. a week before if you requested a week or 2 weeks before if you requested 2 weeks.

Comment: How can you possibly book a one week holiday if you only get approved one week beforehand? Especially if it includes a plane flight?

Comment: @stannius: I have never seen it happening like this in real life. I _have_ seen the exact opposite, where companies forced their employees to book holidays many, many months ahead.

Comment: @gnasher729: Well i would I agree with you. In my case, because they are retailers they are claiming that they have to wait until the calendar of sales, flash sales, vip sales etc will be released

Answer (score 0):

Legality is one thing, the employer being an ass is another. Some people are asked to book their holidays many months ahead. If your husband / wife is in that situation, and your own boss doesn't respond to your request, then at some point you tell him or her that you *will* be going on holiday, and you go. Let's say three months ahead you can ask them whether they agree to the holiday or whether you should look for a job elsewhere.

You comment "I don't think that there are many employers that wouldn't make use of the current legislation." Quite the opposite. I know of employers doing the exact opposite, wanting their employees to book holidays many months ahead. Since you have to be able to take your holiday, there is no point whatsoever in delaying acceptance of a holiday request until the last possible moment. It's *good* for the business to be able to plan far ahead. The only possible reason for a delay is a completely disorganised business.

(This is like laws about maximum and minimum speed driving on a motorway. Many go up to or above the maximum speed, but very few go down to or below the minimum speed).

Comment: Totally agree with you. I didn't have any similar issues with my employer in the past. However, in this case they revealed themselves not only because of the lack of definite response but because of the excuses they bring up.

Unfortunately, I don't think that there are many employers that wouldn't make use of the current legislation.